# wsus cant see client in windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, wsus

I have windows server 2008 working as domain controller, and I have a PFSense firewall and more than 20 workstations.

I installed WSUS on my domain controller correctly and I changed the group policy.

The WSUS started getting updates from Microsoft, but there are no computers in the "unassigned computers" group.

Does anyone know why this would be?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update -> Specify intranet Microsoft update service location` is set to point to your WSUS server.

Computers will only appear in the "unassigned computers" folder after they have checked in, which can be an entire day. You can force an individual workstation to check in by executing `wuauclt /detectnow` at the command prompt or run dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Couple/few things to consider:  first, did you enable access to WSUS by modifying the Windows 2008 firewall policy?  Makes sure BITS is set to automatic on the WSUS clients.  Might consider restarting automatic updates client(s) to apply the policy change(s).  Lastly, sometimes it takes a couple wuauclt.exe /detectnow to get clients to show up on server.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the windowsupdate.log file in the root of the Windows folder to see if its giving any hints as to what is happening on the client end of things.